# Is it ok to put a Triac in my communication path?

Tags: ac, triac, rs485, circuit-protection

I want to protect a differential communications line from 24VAC.  This is an RS485 link running @ 115200.  I have legitimate signals @ +/-5V, but sometimes a foolish technician will hook up a 24VAC power line to it by accident.  This would ruin my RS485 transceiver (maximum voltage on inputs is +/- 14VDC).

I was considering putting a triac in the signal path.  The triac will shut off when a comparator detects rectified signal level over 24VDC.  2 zeners will clip the AC over-voltage @ 10V until the triac closes the path.  Is there a disadvantage to doing this?

Comment: I have seen this: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/99429/57015

Comment: what about burning out the R_term?

Comment: Yes, I will have to think about the termination, thanks Tony

Comment: TVS diodes are the normal protection.

Comment: My foolish technician will likely wire up 200 devices then flip the power switch and walk away for 2 weeks.  As I understand it, TVS diodes are only good for transient/surge.  Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: connect 20kV common mode so it has no affect until some fool touches it. Diodes come in any power level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

- It is very hard to shut off a triac on uprising voltage/current.
- The triac will scramble your communication.

If it can happen only when wiring, and not by a faulty wire insulation, you could use a relay.

Comment: Thanks @Todor, after looking at some relays this seems like a more reasonable solution